# Async functions and object parameter concurrency

Tags: javascript, async-await

So today I encountered this bug that took me forever to figure out:

```
async function embed (url, embedOptions={}) => {
    embedOptions.url = url;
    console.log("Before:");
    console.log(url)
    console.log(embedOptions.url)
    const accessToken = await getAccessToken()
    const requestOptions = {
        hostname: 'api.twitter.com',
        port: 443,
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/1.1/statuses/oembed.json?' + qs.stringify(embedOptions),
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
        },
    }

    console.log("After")
    console.log(url)
    console.log(embedOptions.url)

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        https.request(requestOptions, res => {
            let data = ''
            res.on('data', chunk => data += chunk)
            res.on('end', () => resolve(JSON.parse(data)))
        }).end()
    )
}
```

that function gets called on three different urls which generates the output:

```
Before:
https://twitter.com/326665662/statuses/1233300061154664453
https://twitter.com/326665662/statuses/1233300061154664453
Before:
https://twitter.com/36262503/statuses/1233462038854283264
https://twitter.com/36262503/statuses/1233462038854283264
Before:
https://twitter.com/929823128259387392/statuses/1233431896081629184
https://twitter.com/929823128259387392/statuses/1233431896081629184
After
https://twitter.com/326665662/statuses/1233300061154664453
https://twitter.com/929823128259387392/statuses/1233431896081629184
After
https://twitter.com/36262503/statuses/1233462038854283264
https://twitter.com/929823128259387392/statuses/1233431896081629184
After
https://twitter.com/929823128259387392/statuses/1233431896081629184
https://twitter.com/929823128259387392/statuses/1233431896081629184
```

I'm pretty sure I figured out why this happens basically when `const accessToken = await getAccessToken()` get called the function pauses but next call of the `embed` function happens and overwrites the `embedOptions.url` in the reference to the `embedOptions` object, because all the calss where made with a reference to the same object the object is changed for all function calls.
Is that correct? And if it is what is best way to protect myself from making the same mistake in the future?

Comment: yes, that is correct. Try to not use shared state whenever possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. Any object passed to your function will be passed by reference, and modified when you set the url prop.

The easiest way to guard against these bugs is to be careful not to modify objects. An alternative is to create new objects, using values from your `embedOptions`:

```
const embedCopy = Object.assign({}, embedOptions);
embedCopy.url = url;
```

This will work if your object does not contain objects as values, in which case you would need to do a deep copy of your object.

There are plenty of libs that can deal with this, such as `lodash` or `ramda`.

Comment: If you are running in an ES6 environment the easiest way to make sure you pass a copy of the object instead of a reference is to use the object spread operator to copy properties: `embed(url, { ...options})`. Note though that just like `Object.assign`, this won't do a deep copy

Comment: thanks, i have a habit of passing objects instead of parameters (because i thought of it as a neat way of masking) e.g. `fn(Object.assign(defaults,parameters)` naybe i should dial back on that and be more careful eventhough `fn(Object.assign({},Object.assign(defaults, parameters))` works it seems like error prone code

Comment: You could still send objects, just make sure not to modify the ones you send in. My suggestion is to copy them inside the function definition. You won’t need to do multiple `Object.assign`.

Comment: Yeah, I changed the code to define the defaults within the `embed` function and then assigning the parameters to that object, rather than doing the defaults + parameters masking where I call the function. I think if i wanted to use different defaults in different contexts I think making a function that returns a function with said defaults is the better approach anyway.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help guys, very much appreciated.